# How to whitelist Logic App outbound ip's?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, whitelist, static-ip-address

I got a solution using lots of logic apps and connectors (ftp/sftp) to different partners. My problem is the whitelisting of outbound logic app ip's. I know there is a list of outbound ips but most of the partners will only open up for a handful of ip's for security reasons and the ip's should be static so they won't change often.

So my question, is it possible to have static ip's as outbound ip's for all my logic apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In normal, Azure logic app(Azure Pass service) provides a set of IPs for each region. You can find these IPs from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#configuration).

Besides, if you want to set up the static IP for logic app, you can you can set up an [integration service environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-set-up-single-ip-address) (ISE) for hosting logic apps. Then all the ISE instances can use a single, public, static, and predictable IP address to communicate with the destination systems that you want.

Meanwhile, you also can use Azure API Management to act as a reverse proxy for the Logic App.  Meaning you could set up API Management (which has a [single IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ip-addresses)) to accept calls from the Logic App and proxy them to any end-system you want so they always appear to be from that IP Address regardless of the source. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/32399/azure-logic-apps-with-a-fixed-ip-address.html)

Comment: Does Azure API Management also work with ftp/sftp?