# how often can Azure Logic app Outbound IP addresses change?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to provide my IPs for an external vendor to add it to the white list.
Could you please advice how often logic app change IPs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to whitelist Logic App outbound ip's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526568/how-to-whitelist-logic-app-outbound-ips)

Comment: Using NAT with vNET integration is your way to go if you want specific outbound public IP. Details [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/static-ip-of-logic-app-standard-using-nat-gateway/ba-p/3721443)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the logic app is a server less technology there is no schedule on IP change. However Microsoft does publish a list of IP where you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/common/outbound-ip-addresses
Alternatively if you want to control/fix the outbound IP you can use NAT Gateway here is some reference https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/static-ip-of-logic-app-standard-using-nat-gateway/ba-p/3721443